# Java search a text file

Tags: java

I have made a phone bill system  takes input of phone number called, date of the call and call length. it the saves it in to a text file. what i have not been able to do is search the text file for the phone number.

[My coding](http://pastie.org/3691596)

Comment: It looks like you can read in the file. Thus do that, build a list of call objects and maybe put them into a map of phonenumber to list of calls. Then look up/search the map for a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do linear search (iterating over your phone list) :

```
public static List<Phone> searchPhone(final String phoneNumber, final List<Phone> phoneList) {
    List<Phone> matchedPhone = new ArrayList<Phone>();

    for(Phone phone: phoneList) {
        if ( phone.getphoneNumber().equals(phoneNumber) ) { 
            matchedPhone.add(phone);
        }
    }

    return matchedPhone;
}
```

also for  readability, don't make your method parameter as output. its not good practice, so you should change your method from:

```
static void readList(List<Phone> phoneListIn) {
}
```

to:

```
   static List<Phone> readList(final String fileName) {
   }
```

output arguments should be avoided as possible as you can

Comment: for (Phone Phone, phoneList);                                      comes with an error for the line  that  ';' expected. Although it already has it.

Comment: sorry i use different syntax for foreach loop (this is Qt sytanx) , i updated the answser now, you can use foreach loop or normal loop. for (int i=0; i<phoneList.size(); i++) { /* your code here */ }

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to some code that I found using Google.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48905-search-inside-a-text-file/

Answer (score 2):

Perform `Collections.sort(List list);`

Then perform `Collections.binarySearch(List list, Object key).` This should achieve the searching efficiently.